# urlencode() for RFC 3986

Tags: python, python-3.x, urlencode

Python has a terrific [urlencode()](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=urlencode#urllib.parse.urlencode) function which encodes a `dict` via RFC 1738 (Plus encoding):

```
>>> urllib.parse.urlencode({'site':'Stack Overflow','Coder':'Jeff Atwood'})
'Coder=Jeff+Atwood&site=Stack+Overflow'
```

I cannot find a replacement that uses RFC 3986 (Percent encoding), even though the fine manual [states the following](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/urllib.parse.html):

> RFC 3986 - Uniform Resource Identifiers
>   This is the current standard (STD66). Any changes to urllib.parse module should conform to this.

This would be the expected output:

```
>>> urllib.parse.urlencode({'site':'Stack Overflow','Coder':'Jeff Atwood'})
'Coder=Jeff%20Atwood&site=Stack%20Overflow'
```

Of course I could roll my own, but I find it surprising that I can find no such Python function built in. **Is there such a Python function that I'm just not finding?**

Comment: I assume you're aware of http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote ?  I realize it's not quite what you're asking for (it doesn't take a dict), but it's a start if you need to do part of it yourself.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Right, that would be the essential component of "rolling my own".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there is no such thing built in, but there is a bug requesting one, and it even has a patch attached: http://bugs.python.org/issue13866

Answer (score 1):

For strings you can use this:

```
def percent_encoding(string):
    result = ''
    accepted = [c for c in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._~'.encode('utf-8')]
    for char in string.encode('utf-8'):
        result += chr(char) if char in accepted else '%{}'.format(hex(char)[2:]).upper()
    return result

>>> percent_encoding('http://www.google.com')
'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com'

>>> percent_encoding('ñapa')
'%C3%B1apa'
```

And now, for a dictionary, you need to encode the values, so you only need a function that translate this dictionary to url key/value pairs, encoding only its values.

```
def percent_urlencode(dictionary):
    return '&'.join(["{}={}".format(k, percent_encoding(str(v))) for k, v in dictionary.items()])

>>> percent_urlencode({'token': '$%&/', 'username': 'me'})
'username=me&token=%24%25%26%2F'

>>> percent_urlencode({'site':'Stack Overflow','Coder':'Jeff Atwood'})
'site=Stack%20Overflow&Coder=Jeff%20Atwood'
```